# Replace string with substring with regular expression

Tags: javascript

If I have a string like this `100,000` some digits with `,` followed by some other digits. I need to replace all digits so that the string become `100`.

I have to use a 'replace()' function so please provide the expression.

```
var str = "1200,00";
str.replace("Expression");// Need this.
```

Comment: Regex: *overkill?* `str.split(',')[0]`

Comment: Not an option i have to use replace its in project.

Comment: Then use `str = str.replace(/,.*/, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = "1200,00".split(",")[0];
alert(str);
```

using **`.replace`** it will replace all characters with `''` after the comma.

```js
var str = "1200,00".replace(/,.*/, '');
alert(str);
```

Comment: as i said i need expression i have to use replace . I know how to use split

Comment: Just guessing: the downvote may be for answering a zero-effort question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regular Expression:

```
var str = "1200,00";
str.replace(/,\d+/,'');
```

I tested and it works.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myValue = replace("1200,00");

function replace(str)
{
    var retValue = str.replace(/,\d+/,'');
    return retValue;
}
</script>
```

you can use a function for generic method